# Describe method can only pass with 1 test unless re-rendering each component again and again

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to figure out why my test - which passes when ran alone - is failing whenever the describe block contains more than 1 test. Take this example, which I've taken from my real code and simplified:

```
describe('Create Account Form', () => {
  const {container} = render(<CreateAccountForm />);
  const email = container.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
  const password1 = container.querySelector('input[name="password1"]');

  it('Should render all fields', () => {
    allInputs.forEach((input) => {
      expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  it('Another test', () => {
    expect(email).toBeInTheDocument(); // fails
  });
});
```

The 2nd test fails, but passes only when commenting out the first test, or re-rendering the container again in the test like this:

```
  it('Another test', () => {
    const {container} = render(<CreateAccountForm />);
    const email = container.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
    expect(email).toBeInTheDocument(); // passes
  });
```

Why does this have to happen? I would much rather not have to re-render the container and declare new variables inside each test block.

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the code of the `CreateAccountForm` component. Where does `render` come from? Are you using `@testing-library/react`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTL will unmount React trees that were mounted with render in `afterEach` hook. See [cleanup](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#cleanup).

> Please note that this is done automatically if the testing framework you're using supports the `afterEach` global and it is injected to your testing environment (like mocha, Jest, and Jasmine).

Move the `render` code into `beforeEach` or individual test case. So that we can create react trees before each test case. Isolate test cases from each other, using their own test data without affecting the rest.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function Example() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input name="email" />
      <input name="password1" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';
import { Example } from './';

describe('70753645', () => {
  let email, password1, allInputs;
  beforeEach(() => {
    const { container } = render(<Example />);
    email = container.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
    password1 = container.querySelector('input[name="password1"]');
    allInputs = container.querySelectorAll('input');
  });

  it('Should render all fields', () => {
    allInputs.forEach((input) => {
      expect(input).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });

  it('Another test', () => {
    expect(email).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/70753645/index.test.tsx (9.222 s)
  70753645
    ✓ Should render all fields (24 ms)
    ✓ Another test (3 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.717 s
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: perfect, thank you